# Problem with adding a Service Reference to NetTcpBinding wcf service hosted in win application

Tags: wcf, nettcpbinding

I have a WCF service that is running ok if I add a reference to it when is hosted in IIS, but when I try to host it in win application Client app cant find it. This only happens when I use NetTcpBinding. I get error "There was no endpoint listening at net.tcp://localhost:5566/ that could accept the message". When I'm using basicHttpBinding everything is working.

Here's config file for service

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="TestWcfService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="TestWcfService.Service1Behavior">
    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="TestWcfService.IService1">
      <!-- 
          Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
          identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
          automatically.
      -->
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="TestWcfService.Service1Behavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

And here's code from host app

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1), new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:5566"));
ServiceMetadataBehavior behavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
behavior.HttpGetEnabled = false;
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(behavior);
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), new NetTcpBinding(), "Service1");
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), new NetTcpBinding(), "MEX");
host.Open();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add your TCP endpoint like this:

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1), 
                                   new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:5566"));

host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), new NetTcpBinding(), "Service1");
```

then your service address will be `net.tcp://localhost:5566/Service1` (base address defined in the `ServiceHost` constructor, plus the relative address defined in the `AddServiceEndpoint` call) - have you tried sending a message there??